# Rails 5 + Ajax Table not animating on form submission

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am following a tutorial on rails and AJAX and how to submit a form and load a table with results right after submitting the form, but am having some issues with the item populating the table when submitting my form.

So as it stands right now, the form submits, the data is saved and WILL appear in the table after a page refresh, but I really want a transitional animation and instant page update.

It has been awhile since I have played with something like this so its possible it is just a small error I can't seem to track down.

my index controller action here is my Locations Index:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row" id="container_locations">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><center>Unit number</center></th>
          <th><center>Street number</center></th>
          <th><center>Street name</center></th>
          <th><center>Quad</center></th>
          <th><center>City</center></th>
          <th><center>Province</center></th>
          <th><center>Postal code</center></th>
          <th><center>Tel number</center></th>
          <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% if @locations.present? %>
        <div id="containerLocations">
          <%= render @locations %>
        </div>
        <% else %>
        <td colspan="11"><center><h5>no locations added. please add your first location now.</h5></center></td>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

  <%= link_to 'add office location', '#createLocation', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', :class => 'btn btn-outline-success createLocationBtn' %>
</div>

<%= render partial: 'locations/locations_form' %>
```

My form partial:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="createLocation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for(@location, remote: true) do |f| %>

        <% if @location.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(location.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this location from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
            <% @location.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :unit_number %>
                <%= f.number_field :unit_number, :class => 'form-control unitNum' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :street_number %>
                <%= f.number_field :street_number, :class => 'form-control streetNum' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :street_name %>
                <%= f.text_field :street_name, :class => 'form-control streetName' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :quad, 'quadrant' %>
                <%= f.text_field :quad, :class => 'form-control cityQuad' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :city %>
                <%= f.text_field :city, :class => 'form-control cityName' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :province %>
                <%= f.text_field :province, :class => 'form-control officeProv' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :postal_code %>
                <%= f.text_field :postal_code, :class => 'form-control postalCode' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :tel_number %>
                <%= f.text_field :tel_number, :class => 'form-control telNumber' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-outline-success' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the partial that renders into the @locations:

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="location_<%= location.id %>">
    <td><%= location.unit_number %></td>
    <td><%= location.street_number %></td>
    <td><%= location.street_name %></td>
    <td><%= location.quad %></td>
    <td><%= location.city %></td>
    <td><%= location.province %></td>
    <td><%= location.postal_code %></td>
    <td><%= location.tel_number %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', location %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_location_path(location) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', location, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and finally here is my create.js.erb

```
$("#createLocation").modal('hide');

$(".unitNum").val('');
$(".streetNum").val('');
$(".streetName").val('');
$(".cityQuad").val('');
$(".cityName").val('');
$(".officeProv").val('');
$(".postalCode").val('');
$(".telNumber").val('');

$("#containerLocations").prepend('<%= j render @location %>');
$("#location_<%= @location.id %>").hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this was a small issue I could not track down, the issue was what I was referencing in my create.js.erb

```
$("#containerLocations").prepend('<%= j render @location %>');
```

needed to be:

```
$("#container_locations").prepend('<%= j render @location %>');
```

another issue was where I was placing #container_locations in the index file, I moved it from the `<div>` above the table and placed in in the `<tr>` block and it now functions as it should and places it in the appropriate area.